# Determining convergence of a series $\sum_n (-1)^n \sin a_n $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to determine if the following series is convergent:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\right).$$
I've tried to use alternating series test but got stuck.

Comment: Do you have any context where the series appeared, or do you just play?. Also, $\ln 1=0$, so $1/\ln 1$ is not defined. You might want to start your sum at $n=2$ or so.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I've made a mistake. Series starts at $n=2$

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov This is not *entirely* disinterested, but you feel your question has been addressed, consider accepting the answer (checkmark on the left) to mark it as such. (If not, let me know how I can improve my answer?)

Answer (score 4):

**The series converges:**

Using $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^4)$ around $0$, we get that when $n\to \infty$
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\right)
 = 
\underbrace{\frac{\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n}}}_{a_n} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)}_{b_n}.
$$
The series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n b_n$ converges absolutely by theorems of comparison (as the sum of a Bertrand series and something negligible in front of it), so our original series will be convergent if, and only if, the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  (-1)^n a_n$ converges.

We will show it is indeed convergent (conditionally). We cannot apply the alternating series test, since it does not look like the assumptions (monotonicity and positivity of $a_n$) hold at all. But we can apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test):

- The sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n\geq 1} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})_{n\geq 1}$ is positive and decreasing to $0$;
- The partial sums of the sequence $(\beta)_{n\geq 1} = ((-1)^n \sin 3n)_{n\geq 1}$ are bounded: for all $N\geq 2$,
  $$
  \left\lvert \sum_{n=2}^N \beta_n\right\rvert
  =
  \left\lvert \operatorname{Im} \sum_{n=2}^N (-1)^ne^{i3n}\right\rvert
  =
  \left\lvert \operatorname{Im} \sum_{n=2}^N (e^{(3+\pi)i})^n\right\rvert
  =
  \left\lvert \operatorname{Im}\left( e^{2(3+\pi)i}\frac{1-e^{(3+\pi)i(N-1)}}{1-e^{(3+\pi)i}}\right)\right\rvert \leq M
  $$
  for some absolute constant $M>0$ ($\dagger$). By Dirichlet's test, we therefore have (conditional) convergence of the series
  $$
  \sum_{n=2}^\infty \alpha_n\beta_n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sin 3n}{\sqrt{n}}
  $$
  which by the above implies (conditional) convergence of the original series
  $$
  \sum_{n=2}^\infty  (-1)^n \sin\left(\frac{\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\right).
  $$

($\dagger$) *This step would require more detail, in a full proof.*

Comment: In your first step, you rather use that $\sin x=x+O(x^3)$, right? (That would just be a small simplification for the one reading your nice solution.)

Comment: @mickep  Yes, that is all that is needed indeed... I sort of went with the flow.